# Repeated verification showing last status

Tags: web-app, status

We have just about completed building a verification system for one of the systems we maintain.
Their clients must complete verification of their account and we need to show to the administrators their current verification status.
This is in a grid, and we currently show Not started / In progress / Submitted [for review] / Approved / Declined
When the verification is Declined, it is sent back to their client to resubmit with updated information.

Once a client reaches approved status, this is an end of line state, until the administrators request an update of the verification.
In this scenario, a new *draft* verification is created with the status Not started, but their current verification of Approved status still applies indefinitely.

In this scenario, I need to display both their draft status & their current approved status. 
I don't think adding an extra grid column is the right approach but am struggling to visualize any other way

`Current: Approved
Draft: In progress`

Seems a bit confusing - any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Match the labeling more closely to users' mental models. After their account has been approved, users are likely not expecting to be put into a "draft" status again. It has already been submitted/approved, so how can it be a draft again? This labeling doesn't make sense. Perhaps something like "Update requested/pending" would make more sense.

"Current" is also too vague of a label. Something more like "Application status" is clearer.

As for placement, I would say that's a lesser issue. Just ensure the elements are placed near one another as they are related and likely at the top area/above the fold.

Comment: Thanks! We refer to the draft as Update requested in the user facing copy, draft is our internal status/description for that state.